# How to mock container resolved class with parameters? - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, testing, mocking, mockery

I want to mock a class that is created using a static method

```php
// this is how I instanciate the object
MyClass::from(AnotherClass $data);

// this is how the class looks like
class MyClass 
{
     protected function __construct(AnotherClass $data)
    {
        // do stuff
    }

     public static function from(AnotherClass $data): self
    {
        return new self($data);
    }
}
```

This is how I bind it to the container:

```php
$this->app->bind(MyClass::class, function ($app, array $parameters) {
    return MyClass::from($parameters[0]);
});
```

This is how I use the class

```php
$data = new AnotherClass()
app(MyClass::class, [$data])
```

I cannot store the `$data` globally to get rid of the parameter in my binding.

The problem is that when I try to mock or spy on `MyClass` it does not work.

```php
$spy = spy(MyClass::class);
// ... do some stuff
$spy->shouldHaveReceived('reactPHPIdle');
```

If I dump `app(MyClass::class)` the mocked class is returned. But when I dump `app(MyClass::class, [$data])` the original class is returned, not the mocked one.

How can I successfully mock my class? Is there a better way to do this (ex. refactor the class)?

Comment: From my experience contextual resolution can't be mocked (anymore) making it in practice untestable code

Answer (score 3):

Mocking or spying registers an instance in the container. When providing an argument when resolving will make the container not take the instance, but rather use the bound function to create a new one.

To resolve this issue, you can overwrite the bound function in your test to return the spy. For example something like:

```
app()->bind(MyClass::class, function () use ($spy) {
    return $spy;
});
```